# Remove index.html from url in MVC WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am using angular for frontend and i have a index.html asa start page.

on main page url is looking like this:

localhost:588/index.html#/

and i want it to look like : localhost:3478/#/ or just localhost:3478/

The problem is that i n my Home controller´s Index method i return

```
    public ActionResult Index()
            {
//return File("index.html", "text/html");
            //return ActionResult("~/index.html");
            //return new RedirectResult("~/index.html", true);
                return Redirect(Url.Content("index.html"));
            }
```

And i cant figure out any other ways to make it work. How do i solve my problem?

P.S. outcommented code is something i tryed and it **didnt** work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-Solution 1:

- Move index.html to ~/shared folder and rename it to index.cshtml
- Use the following in your controller:

  ```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {          
      return View();
  }
  ```

2-Solution 2: Read index.html content and return to HTTP response - 
Use the following as your index action in your controller class:

```
    public ActionResult index()
    {
        var myHtmlFile = Server.MapPath("~/Index.html");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(myHtmlFile))
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return Content(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(myHtmlFile), "text/html");
    }
```

In both ways you may need to change the path to access image, css and.js resources in the index.html/cshtml file but that is not a big deal as instead index.html wont appear in address bar.